# If $P$ is an orthogonal projection, prove that $P^+ = P$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection, transpose, pseudoinverse

If $P$ is an orthogonal projection, prove that $P^+ = P$. Where '$^+$' indicates the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

What we know is the $P$ is symmetric and idempotent. That is $P = P^2 = P^T$. I am assuming we just need to check the Penrose conditions?

- $AGA = A \implies PPP = P^2P = PP = P^2 = P$
- $GAG = G \implies PPP = P$ (as above :)).
- $(AG)^T = AG \implies (PP)^T = (P^2)^T = (P)^T = P^T = P = P^2 = PP$
- $(GA)^T = GA\implies (PP)^T = PP$ (as above :)).

Is this what the proof intended? Please let me know if some different was desired.

Comment: Have you proven that the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse is the *unique* transformation satisfying the required conditions? If you have, then obviously checking that it satisfies those conditions will establish that it *is* the Moore-Penrose pseudoinvrse. But if you haven't proven that this characterizes the pseudoinverse, then you would only know these conditions are necessary for it to be the pseudoinverse, and you would still need to show they are also sufficient.

Comment: By unique, I believe I have, if I understand you correctly. The proof (the most basic way, I know) goes simply by assuming some $B,C$ are both pseudo-inverses of some $A$ (or $A=P$ in our case), then deduce that $B = C$, thus a unique pseudo-inverse.

Comment: How do you define the pseudo-inverse? Sometimes one defines it explicitly, then prove it satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions, then prove that *any* transformation that satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions is equal to the explicitly defined pseudo-inverse. Or one can say that *a* pseudo-inverse is any transformation that satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions, then prove that if there are two then they are equal, and then finally show that there is always at least one transformation that satisfies the conditions. Either way, there's stuff that needs to be proven to justify your conclusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I think I see what you are saying. I have to first define what my subspaces that $P$ is an orthogonal projection for, then define what a pseudo-inverse $P^+$ would be defined as, for this particular case? Then show that it is unique and satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions.

Comment: I don't think my point has gotten across. What constitutes a valid proof depends on precisely how (i) you defined the pseudoinverse; and (ii) what properties of the pseudoinverse you have already proven. Your outline would be a valid proof if you had either (1) Defined the pseudoinverse as any matrix that satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions and shown that there is at most one such matrix; or (2) You had defined the pseudoinverse explicitly and then proven that any matrix that satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions is in fact equal to the defined pseudoinverse. (cont)

Comment: (cont) But say you had, instead, defined the pseudoinverse via an explicit construction, then proven that the pseudoinverse satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions, *and nothing else*. So you would not have shown that the Moore-Penrose conditions are both necessary and sufficient for a transformation to be the pseudoinverse, you would only have shown that they are necessary. In that situation, showing that a transformation satisfies the conditions does not *prove* that it is the pseudoinverse, it just proves that it *it is not ruled out*. Whether you have a proof depends on what you've done.

Comment: I understand, I think. So at the beginning, I should have started out with what we know about the pseudo-inverse and have proven to be true that is (1) " ... (i.e., what you said)", at least in my case. Then my outline would be a valid proof @ArturoMagidin?

Comment: If (1) accurately describes what you did (you  may have done more than that, but at least that much), then what you have is a valid proof for your situation.